Error: no such function: json_extract (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR) - React native
Hi i am using react native with watermelon db.
I am using Json extract SQLite method for query. In iOS its working fine but android its showing error as mentioned below
Error: no such function: Json extract (code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)
Thanks

Probably using a version of sqlite built without the json extension

shawn i am using 3.40.1 version.it works fine in some android devices like oppo and not working in realme and moto devices.
